Oracle Database Service: Cloning/Copying an existing database service configuration to create a new service
I am looking to see if anyone else has a "nice way" of cloning an existing service to create a new service with the same configuration.
Say we have a service defined as follows
[oracle@testInst1 ~]$ srvctl config service -d CTESTDB -s ctestdb_app.iperm.ie
Service name: ctestdb_app.iperm.ie
Server pool:
Cardinality: 2
Service role: PRIMARY
Management policy: AUTOMATIC
DTP transaction: false
AQ HA notifications: true
Global: false
Commit Outcome: true
Failover type: AUTO
Failover method:
Failover retries: 30
Failover delay: 10
Failover restore: AUTO
Connection Load Balancing Goal: LONG
Runtime Load Balancing Goal: NONE
TAF policy specification: NONE
Edition:
Pluggable database name: ctestdb_PDB
Hub service:
Maximum lag time: ANY
SQL Translation Profile:
Retention: 86400 seconds
Replay Initiation Time: 600 seconds
Drain timeout: 120 seconds
Stop option: immediate
Session State Consistency: AUTO
GSM Flags: 0
Service is enabled
Preferred instances: CTEST1,CTEST2
Available instances:
CSS critical: no
Service uses Java: false

And I need to add a new service called ctestdb_report with the exact same configuration options.  Does anyone know a handy way of doing this?
Database is 19c
Any comments or advice appreciated.
Looking for a nice way of doing this
